# Flutter calling firebase cloud function admin.auth.updateUser

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, busboy

EDIT**

Ok so I was able to get the parameters working thanks to first answer provided but now I have an issue whereby my function is creating a new user entirely in Firebase and not update an existing one, the uid that i am passing into the auth.admin.updateUser is teh uid of the existing user who's email i want to update. Here is the updated cloud function which is adding a new user rather than updating the existing:

```
    exports.updateEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  const email = data.email;
  const uid = data.uid;

  admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
              email: email
          })
          .then(function(userRecord) {
              // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
              console.log("Successfully updated user", userRecord.toJSON());
              return response.status(200).json(userRecord.toJSON());
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
              console.log("Error updating user:", error);
              return response.status(404).json({
                  error: 'Something went wrong.'
              });
          });
});
```

I got the function from the firebase docs but it isn't doing what I intended it to do.

ORIGINAL POST**

I'm having some difficulty getting a cloud function to work when calling the function from within my flutter code. The issue that I am having is that the uid and email fields are undefined even though I am passing them through to the cloud function using busboy fields.

I'm trying to pass the email and uid field though to the function as follows:

```
final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('****************my function url************'));

request.fields['email'] = Uri.encodeComponent(newEmail);
request.fields['uid'] = Uri.encodeComponent(selectedUser.uid);

request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ${_authenticatedUser.token}';

  final http.StreamedResponse streamedResponse = await request.send();
```

And on the Node.js side I am trying to use these fields using busboy, here is my cloud function in Node.js:

```
exports.changeEmail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

if (!request.headers.authorization ||
    !request.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')
) {
    return response.status(401).json({
        error: 'Unauthorized.'
    });
}

let idToken;
idToken = request.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
let email;
let uid;

const busboy = new Busboy({
    headers: request.headers
});

busboy.on('field', (fieldname, value) => {

    if (fieldname == 'email') {


        email = decodeURIComponent(value);
    }

    if (fieldname == 'uid') {

        uid = decodeURIComponent(value);
    }
});



admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
        email: email
    })
    .then(function(userRecord) {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        console.log("Successfully updated user", userRecord.toJSON());
        return response.status(200).json(userRecord.toJSON());
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error updating user:", error);
        return response.status(404).json({
            error: 'Something went wrong.'
        });
    });
```

});

Even though I am passing the fields in with busboy fields they are not getting set in the function, is there something I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)? It will automatically receive the authentication data.

The documentation even has examples on how to get the uid and email:

Declare the function:

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

Get the user properties from the context parameter:

```
// Message text passed from the client.
const text = data.text;
// Authentication / user information is automatically added to the request.
const uid = context.auth.uid;
const name = context.auth.token.name || null;
const picture = context.auth.token.picture || null;
const email = context.auth.token.email || null;
```

Call the function from your Flutter code:

Install [cloud_functions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_functions) package and then:

```
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';

await CloudFunctions.instance.call(functionName: 'addMessage');
```

If the user is authenticated before calling the function that's all you need to do.

You can also pass additional parameters to the function:

```
await CloudFunctions.instance.call(functionName: 'addMessage', parameters: {"email": "whatever@example.com"});
```

Any parameters will be passed to the data parameter on the function side.

Comment: Thank you so much worked perfectly!! There was a slight issue with iOS not setting the region correctly in the cloud functions package but after fixing that i've successfully managed to update users emails as an admin in my app!! I gave you an upvote but I don't have enough reputation for it to show!

Comment: However now I have an issue with my function itself, i'm wanting to update an existing users email but instead it seems to be adding a new user entirely

Comment: admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
              email: email
          })
          .then(function(userRecord) {
              // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
              console.log("Successfully updated user", userRecord.toJSON());
              return response.status(200).json(userRecord.toJSON());
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
              console.log("Error updating user:", error);
              return response.status(404).json({
                  error: 'Something went wrong.'
              });
          });

Comment: Glad it worked! But is it creating a new user with a different uid? Maybe if you create a new question with this specific problem and the details it will be easier for people to help you.

Comment: @RicardoSmania I see that you can pass a key:value pair as `parameters: {"email": "whatever@example.com"}`, so inside the function will it be present as `data.email` or `data` need to json decoded and then get the `email` parameter from it ?